# Dual Boot - backup & recovery

Tags: dual-boot, backup

When I was relatively new to Ubuntu and I created a dual boot system with Ubuntu 14.04 and Win 8 (now win 10).  Things work fine but now I'd like to be able to back up and recover (just in case).  I've got two 1 TB hard drives and I see that I have Ubuntu on one and Win on the other.  Is there a way to combine both on to one drive, so I can use the freed up drive to image or clone the drive containing Ubuntu & Win?  If I could possibly avoid a re-install that would be preferred.

Comment: So your saying that each operating system is on a different hard drive in the same computer and they're dual booting?

Comment: You could already just image each hard drive you have, individually. I.e. using a tool like clonezilla, create an image of the Windows HDD, and store it on the Ubuntu one, and also create an image of the Ubuntu one, and store it on the Windows one. This would also protect you from drive failure, and would probably be easier than moving things around first.

Comment: I thought it would be simpler to clone or image one drive instead of doing this is two steps.  It appears that Windows 10 is on SDA and Ubuntu is on SDB.  In moving all partitions to one drive does it matter whether it's SDA or SDB.  Also, any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it would be possible, but it will take some time. Now I have never done exactly what your trying to do, but what I would do is use the GParted live CD and shrink down the partitions on both hard drives so that both or all the partions would fit on one drive. Then on the drives check which one has the boot label most likely the one with Ubuntu is my guess since your using grub. Then you would want to use a cloning tool(Like CloneZilla) and copy the other hard disk onto the one that has a partition marked with the boot flag. make sure and copy all the partitions as it will most likely mess up if you don't. After that you'll need to boot into Ubuntu and do a grub update(You can look up on google how to do it is really easy. You should be ready after that.

Comment: It's been awhile since I cloned something, but I think you may need to create partitions on the main hard drive equal or slightly greater in size to the ones that are on the second hard drive so you can clone separate partitions over instead of trying to over write the whole drive.(One other note, if the total in partitions is over 4 on both hard drives you may have a problem.)